How does a rocket burning fuel at a constant rate affect its acceleration?
Say a rocket travelling in space is burning its fuel at a constant rate. By expelling the burnt fuel through a nozzle, the engine is applying a constant force to the rocket.
What is happening to the magnitude of the acceleration of the rocket?
My thinking is that if the force is to stay constant and the mass is decreasing at a constant rate because the rocket is burning its fuel at a constant rate, the acceleration of the rocket will increase at a constant rate: $F=(m\downarrow )(a\uparrow$)
However, the answer in my past paper says that the acceleration will increase at an increasing rate.
Am I completely misunderstanding something? Thank you very much, any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Why is "the engine [...] applying a constant force to the rocket"? Consider that (at a given burning temperature) the engine is ejecting exhaust gas at a constant speed.

Does this help? @ https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_I_-Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves(OpenStax)/09%3A_Linear_Momentum_and_Collisions/9.11%3A_Rocket_Propulsion

Let us first take a visual, graphed approach to your question.
$$
\begin{equation}
F = ma \tag{1}
\end{equation}
$$
Hence rearranging $ (1) $ gives:
$$
a=\frac{F}{m}
$$
Note that m represents the total mass of the rocket and the fuel at any instant - as you have said already, due to the burning of the fuel for propulsion, m is decreasing at a constant rate.
Now consider a graph of a on the y-axis against m on the x-axis; since F is a constant, this graph is simply a scale of the reciprocal function $y=\frac{1}{x}$. Hence, the acceleration-mass graph has the following shape:

Without using derivatives with respect to time to find rates of change (which would actually be a far more rigorous, clearer, and better proof in most cases), we can develop an intuition for why the acceleration increases at an increasing rate:

Start at a point somewhere towards the right of the positive m-axis.
Move to the left along the m-axis at a constant speed, towards the origin.
As you do this, note that the acceleration increases at an increasing rate - if it increased at a constant rate, it would be a straight line!

If we were to introduce derivatives, it would become clear at once that the rate of change of the acceleration is indeed NOT constant:

Consider the graph of acceleration against mass shown above, once again.

The gradient of this graph is given by the derivative of a with respect to m, i.e. $ \frac{da}{dm} $.

Using the chain rule (connected rates of change), we obtain $ \frac{da}{dm} = \frac{da}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dm} $

Hence, for the rate of change of acceleration ($ \dot{a} $ in dot notation), we obtain the following expression, also using the chain rule:
$ \begin{equation}
\frac{da}{dt} = \frac{dm}{dt}\cdot\frac{da}{dm} \tag{2}
\end{equation}$

Now recall that the rate of change of mass due to the burning of the fuel is constant, i.e. $ \frac{dm}{dt}=-k $, where $k$ is a real positive constant (and hence -k is negative for purposes explained in the next bullet point).

Note that $ \frac{dm}{dt} $ (or $ \dot{m} $, set equal to the constant $-k$) is less than $0$, since the rocket is losing mass as time progresses (fuel is burned and therefore lost).

Going back to $(2)$ and substituting our mass loss rate constant $-k$ for $\frac{dm}{dt}$:
$\begin{equation}
\frac{da}{dt} = -k\frac{da}{dm} \tag{3}
\end{equation}$

Now, for m>$0$, the graph of acceleration against mass shown above has a "downwards" curve; mathematically speaking, its gradient is always negative as we can clearly see on the graph i.e. $ \frac{da}{dm} < 0 $ and so is negative for the ranges of masses we are considering (m>$0$).

Let us actually compute the derivative of the acceleration with respect to the mass, in terms of the constant force F, and the changing mass m: $a=\frac{F}{m}=Fm^{-1}$, hence $\frac{da}{dm} = -Fm^{-2}=-\frac{F}{m^{2}}.$ As seen, we have verified that the rate of change of the acceleration with respect to the mass is indeed always negative, in fact for all m - but we do not consider masses $0$ and below (this is impossible, at least so far in our knowledge of physics!).

Going back to $(3)$, consider the right-hand side of the equation: $-k$ is always negative, and we have just found that $\frac{da}{dm}$ is also always negative. Hence, $\frac{da}{dt}$ ($\dot{a}$) is always positive, since a negative number multiplied by a negative number gives a positive number. Substituting our computed value for $\frac{da}{dm}$ into $(3)$:
$\begin{equation}
\frac{da}{dt}=-k(-\frac{F}{m^{2}}) \tag{4} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{da}{dt}=k\frac{F}{m^{2}} 
\end{equation}$

Finally, $k$ is positive and so is $\frac{F}{m^{2}}$, hence we have confirmed that the rate of change of acceleration, $\frac{da}{dt}$ ($\dot{a}$) is also positive and greater than $0$ for all possible mass values for the rocket; we have therefore obtained the result:
$\begin{equation}
\dot{a}>0 \tag{5}
\end{equation}$

From $(5)$ we deduce that the acceleration is certainly increasing, since its rate of change is positive - but how do we know that it is not simply a positive constant and therefore increasing at a constant rate?

Well, more importantly, to answer that question, since $\dot{a}=k\frac{F}{m^{2}}$, for decreasing values of mass m, the rate of acceleration increases - for smaller values of the mass, the rate of increase of the acceleration $\dot{a}$ is greater, which clearly tells us that for a constant rate of decrease of m, the acceleration increases at an increasing rate!


I hope that this answer has been useful.

If you decrease $x$ at a constant rate, $\frac 1x$ does not increase at a constant rate.
As the acceleration is basically similar to this division (constant force and decreasing mass), its behavior is the same.

So if you have fuel mass $m$ and dry rocket mass $M$, and a constant thrust $F$ and fuel loss rate $\dot m$, then:
$$ F = "m"a \rightarrow (M+m)a $$
so
$$ a = \frac F {M+m}$$
and
$$ \dot a = \frac{F\dot m}{(M+m)^2} > 0 $$
